# How can I get bpy.ops.import_scene.obj to import all texture files and materials properly?

Tags: import, obj

I'm using Blender 2.91 in a docker file, and upgrading it isn't a realistic option. I need import a .obj file that includes material and textures. When I use

```
bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=file_name)
```

I get the following warning

```
WARNING: '/home/loki/OneDrive/Documents/workspace/vto/workfolder/garment.obj':b'map_Ns W507_ZippedTop_Colorway 1-textures/outside_tex89ddad70_roughness.png' (ignored)
```

The .mtl file is printed below for reference

The object will import correctly, but the material for it is wrong. Some of the textures are loaded, others are not, and the textures are mapped to incorrect inputs on the shader node.

If I use the new obj importer from Blender 3+ `bpy.ops.wm.obj_importer` the object properly imports and all materials are correct.
Sadly this command is not available with the version of Blender I'm tied to. I'm wondering anyone has seen this before, and has any advice on how to modify the .obj of .mtl file to makes this work.

**object.mlt**

````
Ns 0.999999
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.450000
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd W507_ZippedTop_Colorway 1-textures/outside_tex898a1d87_basecolor.png
map_Ks W507_ZippedTop_Colorway 1-textures/outside_tex89ddad70_specular.png
map_Ns W507_ZippedTop_Colorway 1-textures/outside_tex89ddad70_roughness.png
map_refl W507_ZippedTop_Colorway 1-textures/outside_tex89ddad70_metalness.png
map_Bump -bm 3.000000 W507_ZippedTop_Colorway 1-textures/outside_tex89b29bb7_normal.png```
````